# Search API returns QueryError when Query contains ','(Comma) or = or ()

Tags: python, google-app-engine, full-text-search

Using app engine's search API, I tried to search the queries which contain `,`, `=`, `(`, etc.
It returns the following error:

```
Failed to parse query "engines (Modular)"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1505, in __call__
  rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1253, in default_dispatcher
  return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1077, in __call__
  return handler.dispatch()
File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 547, in dispatch
  return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 545, in dispatch
  return method(*args, **kwargs)
File "/base/data/home/apps/s~generatestock/12.362076640167792770/search.py", line 1641, in get
  result = find_search_document(search_item)
File "/base/data/home/apps/s~generatestock/12.362076640167792770/search.py", line 177, in find_search_document
  return search.Index(name=_INDEX_NAME).search(query)
File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/search/search.py", line 2715, in search
  query = Query(query_string=query)
File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/search/search.py", line 2286, in __init__
_CheckQuery(self._query_string)
File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/search/search.py", line 1964, in _CheckQuery
  raise QueryError('Failed to parse query "%s"' % query)

QueryError: Failed to parse query "Engines (Modular)"
```

Why? Does the search API support these characters?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To parse a phrase, use quotes around the phrase:

```
query = '"Engines (Modular)"'
search.Index(name=_INDEX_NAME).search(query)
```

You can simply put quotes around an existing query:

```
query = '"{0}"'.format(query)
search.Index(name=_INDEX_NAME).search(query)
```

but you probably have to *remove* existing quotes in the query to make this work. Google's documentation is silent on how to include quotes in your search queries. So the complete, fail-safe method would be:

```
query = '"{0}"'.format(query.replace('"', ''))
search.Index(name=_INDEX_NAME).search(query)
```